# Play-Services for Froyo not to be found on gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, backwards-compatibility, android-2.2-froyo

I know that there is a new way of handling [Maps in our applications](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html), specifically if we want to have support for Android 2.2 and below. The new library `google-play-services-for-froyo` can be downloaded via the SDK Manager

But I can't seem to find the gradle URL. [Gradle, please](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/) only gives the

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32'
```

standard line. 
I was able to find the following in the `Manifest.xml` of the downloaded library in the "extras" folder on my hard drive:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms"
    android:versionCode="3265130"
    android:versionName="3.2.65 (834000-30)" >
```

But when I try to sync

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.65'
```

I dont seem to get the correct version an when I sync

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-for-froyo:3.2.65'
```

I don't get anything but an error

So the question is: **where can I find the play services fro froyo on gradle?**

Comment: in fact you are looking for maven aar file with this lib ... short answer they didnt provided ... you have to import `ANDROID_SDK\extras\google\google_play_services_froyo\libproject\google-play-services_lib` as module into your Project in Android Studio, then add this module as dependency to your main app module in standard way ...

Comment: so why didn't they? is there a reason?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add it to Android Studio as a module. I'm assuming you've seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/20640084/507339 . So the question is why don't you seem to get the correct version when you sync using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.65'? What goes wrong? It is supposed to be the correct procedure.